# JavaScript Associative array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I was trying to create an associative array in javascript, but since it is not supported I am having a lot of troubles.
I want to create the following database in mongoDB:

[Image of mongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSpEa.png)

[JavaScript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlnsG.png)

When I sent the HTTP POST request from the postman it works fine (like dataSet 5 from the pic). 
But when I try with javascript the request do not work. (dataSet 6 from pic).
The 'extras' field is going to change. it depends on the app in use. That is why I need it to be like DataSet 5.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Fix it by using JQuery

Comment: Could you post some of your code (preferably the least amount possible to recreate the problem), and what have you tried to fix it so far?

Comment: I edit the post. 
As you can see from the picture I tried different ways to implement the "associative array". But in MongoDB it always appears like Extras: [Object object] . and I know the problem is in my request or in the array. In postman, since it support associative arrays, it all work fine.

Comment: Javascript objects just ARE associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What specific features does an associative array have?

Essentially it has the same characteristics as an object.

Instead of inserting `array['key'] = value` you insert the object like

```
"associativeArray": {
    "key": "value"
}
```

Several objects can be put in an array like

```
"images": [
    {
        "key": "value"
    },
    {
        "key": "value"
    }
]
```

Comment: I already try with objects, the problem is that I want the objects inside the 'Extras' field. and with objects, I think I cannot do that.
EDIT: I try to do like you said, it did not work.

Comment: @CatarinaFranco `extras` already is an object. You can even nest them `extras.someobject.key`

Comment: It did not work. But I think the problem is on the request now. I will work on it now. Many thanks